# What is the rationale in allowing `?` to be escaped?

Tags: c++, language-design, language-lawyer

From **2.13.2/3**

> The double quote `"` and the question mark `?`, can be represented as
>   themselves or by the escape sequences `\"` and `\?` [...].

Simply put, the following:

```
char x = '\?'; //or '\"'
char y = '?';  //or '"'
```

represent the same character. Why treat these two (especially `?`) differently than other characters?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`\"` gives consistency between single-quoted character literals and double-quoted string literals (they're defined to use the same escape sequences, as a result `\'` and `\"` can be used in both). I'm slightly guessing, but I reckon the committee just figured it was too much bother to define different escape sequences in each, for no benefit and arguably a slight detriment.

`\?` is for avoiding trigraphs: `??=` is a trigraph, `?\?=` isn't.

Comment: \? is indeed something to do with trigraphs, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt0y4awe.aspx for an explanation.