# What's the purpose of the "\'" escape sequence?

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the rationale in allowing `?` to be escaped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241313/what-is-the-rationale-in-allowing-to-be-escaped)

If I can do this:

```
string i = "'";
```

Why do this:

```
string i = "\'";
```

Comment: See if you can do `"""` . you will get the answer..

Comment: *"""* is not the same as *"'"*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need it if you want a character literal:

```
char apos = '\'';
```

Answer (score 6):

You need it if you require a `'` char:

```
char c = '\'';
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it's just for consistency between character constants and string literals.

The language *could* have required a string literal containing a single apostrophe to be written as `"'"` and not as `"\'"`, a character constant containing a double quote to be written as `'"'` and not as `'\"'`.  (And of course `"'"` and `'"'` are both perfectly valid.)

Allowing, but not requiring, `'` to be escaped in string literals, and `"` to be escaped in character constants, makes the language just a little bit more flexible, lets string literals and character constants use the same set of escapes, and does no particular harm.

As for why you *should* use one form or the other, that's up to you. Use whichever form you're more comfortable with.

Answer (score 1):

Like Kerrek said, you escape the character if you want the literal character and not the evaluated one. For example, "\"" or a literal parenthesis inside a regular expression. It keeps the interpreter from evaluating the escaped character as anything but the actual character value.

Answer (score 1):

For suppose if you want to generate a html for an anchor from serverside obviously you will use string.format like below...

```
  X = string.Format("<a href=\"tel:{0}\" onclick=\"Javascript: goog_report_conversion({1}); return false;\">{0}</a>", displayText, sRegPhone);
```

we need double quotations for the function call and href in anchor , but will error out to use 
like below at server in a statement..

```
  "<a href="tel:{0}""></a>
```

so, inorder to overcome this we use escape sequence , which in turn escapes(won't consider) the next literal to \ in server side , but will generate along with that skipped literal in the output area or client side...like below

```
<a onclick="Javascript: goog_report_conversion(2818669180); return false;" href="tel:(281) 866-9180">(281) 866-9180</a>
```

so mostly it is used for escaping the upcoming literal......

Answer (score 0):

in plain English I can one can say that the authors of the language had to use some special characters to compile the code

so in order to enable the programmers to use this characters they used the method of using "/"

it prevail in almost all the languages

Answer (score 0):

The `\` is the character used to escape "special characters". What does that mean?

This means that the parser does *magical things* when encountering certain characters. These *magical things* are changes of state during parsing. A change of state is something like: now you enter a string literal, now you go to the next line, now you leave a character constant etc.

The '\' character was chosen to suppress the *magical meaning* of the character it precedes. So a `\` at the end of a line will suppress its meaning, allowing to construct, for instance, macros on several lines in the editor but seen as 1 lexem by the pre-processor (the pre-processor uses the new-line as delimiter).

If you precede a `"` with a `\` it will suppress its meaning of start or end of string literal, the same with `'`.

It was also convened that a `\` preceding a *non-magical* character will only be ignored (you cannot suppress magic when there is none). Therefore is it not a problem to write "\'". The `'` has no magical meaning within a string literal and the escaping is simply ignored. You can precede any character with `\` within a string literal without problem (except of course digits and `x` for octal, decimal and hex characters).